# How do I enforce code style in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to set my IntelliJ IDEA such that every new line must conform to the defined styling rules. There must be a magic checkbox somewhere.

For instance, the I want to have space between `)` and `{` in `if` statements.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-style-java.html (Spaces section). Then reformat the code: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reformatting-source-code.html.

Comment: I saw that documentation.  But my question is about automating this reformatting.  Is it possible to reformat automatically the edited code?

Comment: No, you can reformat on Save using the Save Actions plug-in or you can Reformat when commiting to the Version Control, but not on the fly as you type.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reformat the code using one of the following ways:

- [Reformat manually](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reformatting-source-code.html) (via the menu action or the keyboard shortcut)
- On Save using the [Save Actions plug-in](https://github.com/dubreuia/intellij-plugin-save-actions)
- [Reformat when committing to the Version Control](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-changes-dialog.html#before_commit)

Reformatting on the fly as you type is not possible.